# Variable getting new value in same loop iteration

Tags: python, variables, dictionary, scope, renaming

I'm running into an issue where basically a variable I set at the top of the loop is getting a new value before the end of the iteration. How do I change this so it doesn't happen? I think it has something to do with scope, but I'm not entirely sure. Relevant code and output below:

```
while not stop(old_centers, centers): #returns True when old centers == new ones
    
    old_centers = centers #setting old centers to centers, nothing fancy
    print 'old_centers', old_centers

    centers = label(points, centers)#calls the label func and assigns centers a new value

    print 'old centers ', old_centers, '\n new ones ', centers

    print '# of iterations: %d' % iterations
    iterations += 1
```

And here is the output:

> initial centers  {'1': [1.193013180404786, 1.3490890491331484], '0': [0.10173245995124558, 0.2259745323785607], '2': [1.1969102753605907, 1.1584028826056012]}
>
> old_centers {'1': [1.193013180404786, 1.3490890491331484], '0': [0.10173245995124558, 0.2259745323785607], '2': [1.1969102753605907, 1.1584028826056012]}
>
> new centers in label  {'1': [1.1646709311677974, 1.7595898757959954], '0': [0.23028481023828123, 0.9213541910575308], '2': [1.3055269036979071, 0.6867418777771471]}
>
> old centers  {'1': [1.1646709311677974, 1.7595898757959954], '0': [0.23028481023828123, 0.9213541910575308], '2': [1.3055269036979071, 0.6867418777771471]}
>
> new ones  {'1': [1.1646709311677974, 1.7595898757959954], '0': [0.23028481023828123, 0.9213541910575308], '2': [1.3055269036979071, 0.6867418777771471]}
>
> # of iterations: 0

As you can see, my **old_centers** variable is changed by the end of the loop, forcing the while loop to cancel after the first iteration. At first, it correctly receives the initial dict, but after **label** is called, it changes and I have no idea why. Any tips on why this is happening?

Comment: You should probably show the implementation of the `label` function. It appears to be mutating its argument, which is why you see what you see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `copy.deepcopy`,just  using copy will **not** work as you have lists as values so any changes in any list will also change in `old_centers`:

```
from copy import deepcopy

old_centers = deepcopy(centers)
```

`old_centers = centers` creates a reference to `centers` so any changes to `centers` are reflected in `old_centers` as both objects are pointing to the same location in memory, both are in fact the same object. `c is d`:

```
d = {1:2}
c = d
d[1] = 4
print(id(c),id(d))
print(c,d)
print(c is d)

140661961276040 140661961276040 # same id same objects
{1: 4} {1: 4}
True
```

Now copy:

```
from copy import deepcopy
d = {1: 2}
c = deepcopy(d) # create new object
d[1]= 4
print(id(c),id(d))
print(c,d)
print(c is d) 

140477200628872 140477200628360 # now two different id's two different objects
{1: 2} {1: 4}
False
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much! I also learned something new about Python objects and references, thanks again :)